# unable to install.packages('arrow') to read parquet file (read_parquet). Any other way to read parquet file or use any different library?

Tags: r, parquet, install.packages, apache-arrow

I'm very new to R or even bash. I'm trying to read Parquet file from my local using read_parquet function, but it requires to install arrow library: install.packages('arrow'), which is taking forever (read it as stuck/hang on installation step) on my Ubuntu WSL.
I have tried everything else.

```
install.packages('arrow')  #Taking forever to install
library(arrow)
df <- read_parquet("Financial_Sample.parquet")
```

Could someone please help me to find any other function or library to read parquet file. any lead would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

To be able to use `read_parquet`, I had to install `arrow` with:

```
Sys.setenv(LIBARROW_MINIMAL = "false")
install.packages("arrow")
```

which installs `arrow` with the following capabilities:

```
dataset    TRUE
parquet    TRUE
json       TRUE
s3         TRUE
utf8proc   TRUE
re2        TRUE
snappy     TRUE
gzip       TRUE
brotli     TRUE
zstd       TRUE
lz4        TRUE
lz4_frame  TRUE
lzo       FALSE
bz2        TRUE
jemalloc   TRUE
mimalloc   TRUE
```

Comment: This works IMHO if one has the required C++ libs installed. I.e. libbrotli-dev on Debian.

Comment: I have brotli installed on my system too. But I would say that the arrow installation process builds the missing libraries,  see `arrow/cpp/cmake_modules/ThirdpartyToolchain.cmake`.

Comment: I stand corrected. Indeed the cmake you file you pointed apparently defines the required source files for dependencies. Really good to know.

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way I found to install on remote servers:

```
Sys.setenv(NOT_CRAN = "true")
install.packages("arrow")
```

This is the recommended method based on the warning messages I also got from a hanging (forever) load time with a standard CRAN install.

Answer (score 0):

Check:

```
library(arrow)
arrow_info()
Arrow package version: 6.0.1

Capabilities:
               
dataset    TRUE
parquet    TRUE
json       TRUE
<snip>
```

The default install of arrow in R does not provide you with bunch of compression algorithms (or rather any of these):

```
snappy    FALSE
gzip      FALSE
brotli    FALSE
zstd      FALSE
lz4       FALSE
lz4_frame FALSE
lzo       FALSE
bz2       FALSE
```